# Проблемы с запуском цикла

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def hello():
        for i in range(5):
                hi = random.randint(1,60)
                time.sleep(5)
                return hi                

class New_Toplevel_1:

   def __init__(self, top=None):

    priceTag = hello()  
    self.Label1.configure(text=priceTage)
```

Мне необходимо обновлять Label в Tkinter каждый 5 секунд. Как запустить этот цикл? Сейчас он показывает только первое рандомное число.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас на первой же итерации используется `return`, которые завершает работу функции вместе с циклом. Во-вторых, метод `__init__` вызывается один раз, до отрисовки окна. Если бы даже цикл не заканчивался сразу, вы бы 5 секунд ждали пока появится окно, а потом увидели бы в метке последнее значение цикла.

Помочь может метод [after](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5_Tkinter_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_Python#after,_after_idle_%D0%B8_after_cancel[3])

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.update_label()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update_label(self):
        self.label.configure(text=random.randint(1, 60))
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_label)


app=App()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Сергей! Но как мне его имплементировать в https://pastebin.com/jd9MFeBS

Comment: Так же как здесь, сделать функцию изменяющую текст метки и назначающую своё выполнение через секунду с помощью метода `after`.